# CS50 pset2, get initials of a name

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, cs50

I am getting segmentation fault in the below code.

```
char name[30];
char initials[10];
int i=0, j=0;
int size;

printf("Getting name: ");
name = Getstring();
size = strlen(name);

while(i < size)
{
    if(i == 0)
    {
         initials[j] = toupper(name[i]);
         j++;
    }
    else
    {
         if(name[i - 1] == ' ')
         {
              initials[j] = toupper(name[i]);
              j++;
         }
    }
    i++;
}
initials[j] = '\0';
printf("%s",initials);
    }
}
```

When I debugged it (by gdb in cs50 appliance), I found the fault in this statement:
    initials[j] = toupper(name[i]);

Any ideas here? Please help.. :(

Answer (score 0):

There are, at least, 2 problems in your code:

1. `name` assignment: `name = Getstring();` 
   `name` is a char **array**, you can't just assign it a value like you would do with e.g. an `int`. You should use something like `strcpy()` to copy a new string into it. This way, `name` would hold a meaningful string on which you can use `strlen()`,
2. Character assignment: `initials[j] = toupper(name[i]);` 
   I get that you assume that a `name` can't have more than `10` initials (therefore, `j` is probably always `< 10`. However, you should always take extreme cases into consideration in order to protect your program from the (evil) user input. Try using this condition in your loop: `while(i < size && j < 10)`

Comment: Hey Jongware. Thanks. But before trying the said code, I tried declaring name as string data type( a type for string available in 1 of the header files in CS50 appliance). The rest of the code was exactly the same. There also I was getting the same thing.